# Python requests, multipart without files

Tags: python, python-requests

Is it possible to send a multipart/form-data with python requests without sending a file?

My requests header should look like this:

```
--3eeaadbfda0441b8be821bbed2962e4d
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="value";

content
--3eeaadbfda0441b8be821bbed2962e4d--
```

But actually it looks like this:

```
--3eeaadbfda0441b8be821bbed2962e4d
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="file"
Content-Type: text/plain

content
--3eeaadbfda0441b8be821bbed2962e4d--
```

I'm using this function:

```
response = requests.post('url', data, files=('file', 'file'))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you could, just pass dictionary with tuples as values to post method. When you specify `files` parameter to this method `requests` add `multipart/form-data` header. But you free to pass dictionary with tuples as `files`:

```
url = 'http://httpbin.org/post' 
files = {'file': (None, 'some,data,to,send\nanother,row,to,send\n')}
r = requests.post(url, files=files)
```

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file

Comment: It works, but I don't need the filename="hello" part in the header of the request. Is there a simple way to remove it?

Comment: what are you talking about? Please show me your headers.

Comment: The header I want to get is the first code I posted. What I'm actually getting is the second code I posted. In the request I don't need the filename="..." part. Is there a simple way to remove that string from the request?

Comment: I understand now, you can pass None as filename: `files = {'file': (None, 'some,data,to,send\nanother,row,to,send\n')}` Than header will be without `filename`.