# python requests login with "multipart/form-data"

Tags: python, python-requests

Today I tried to login on a website using `python` requests. That website is using `multipart/form-data` to login.
I tried to get the http request going through the web.

This is what I got:

```
1
-----------------------------25373143914744
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="csrfKey"
c720e331f5ba76c1ca5d389adfecbf7f
-----------------------------25373143914744
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ref"
aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuY3JhY2tpbmdvZXouY29tLz9fZnJvbUxvZ291dD0x
-----------------------------25373143914744
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="MAX_FILE_SIZE"
7340032
-----------------------------25373143914744
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="plupload"
b8f090b305d37f4f77bbf7966aa6e932
-----------------------------25373143914744
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="auth"
deewfwef
-----------------------------25373143914744
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="password"
wefwefwef
-----------------------------25373143914744
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="remember_me"
0
-----------------------------25373143914744
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="remember_me_checkbox"
1
-----------------------------25373143914744
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="signin_anonymous"
0
-----------------------------25373143914744--
```

Is there any way to login a website that using "multipart/form-data" with python requests?

How can I send this details to the server and get back the response?

Comment: a) make a dict with names and values, b) post that dict.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python requests, multipart without files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34451685/python-requests-multipart-without-files)